# Check whether less than some amount of free disk space from the command line

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, df

There are several questions and answers on askubuntu about seeing disk space from the command line.

Naturally, `df` is the go-to tool for this.

However I want a script at login to raise an alert if the free disk space is below some threshold.

Unfortunately `df` seems to use arbitrarily sized columns and I'm not sure how to extract just the value from the column I'm interested in.

For example:

```
$ df /dev/mapper/root
Filesystem       1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/root   2563092 1649968    763212  69% /
$ df /dev/mapper/root | tail -n 1
/dev/mapper/root   2563092 1649968    763212  69% /
$ df /dev/mapper/root | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 9
763212
```

Really I want the fourth column, yet I must ask for the ninth.

Is there an easier way to either extract the column's value from `df`'s output, or another way altogether to access this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu 14.04 or later, `df` can output only the values you want it to:

```
$ df --output=avail /
   Avail
15127808
```

From [`man df`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/df.1.html):

```
--output[=FIELD_LIST]
      use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields
      if FIELD_LIST is omitted.
...
FIELD_LIST  is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  Valid
field names  are:  'source',  'fstype',  'itotal',  'iused',  'iavail',
'ipcent',  'size',  'used',  'avail',  'pcent'  and  'target' (see info
page).
```

As noted by [Drew Noakes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542924/check-whether-less-than-some-amount-of-free-disk-space-from-the-command-line/542929?noredirect=1#comment743478_542929), this ability was added in GNU `coreutils` 8.21, and so isn't available in older versions of Ubuntu.

For selecting fields, `awk` is a far better tool than `cut`, and you can build on Jan's answer for that after picking the fields you want `df` to output.

Comment: Note, the `--output=` option was only added to `df` in GNU coreutils 8.21, which means it's not available in Ubuntu 13.10, but is in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Indeed! I hadn't noticed that. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

Just realized that this isn't what was asked for, this shows an alert if the space used is greater than a predefined threshold. I'll leave it for further reference though.

You could use something like the script below

```
#!/bin/bash
X=
X=$(du -sc | awk 'NR < 2' | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [ $X -gt 999000 ]; then
  message="Already using `du -sch | awk 'NR <2' |awk '{ print $1 }'` KB"
echo $message | mail -s "File System Full Warning" email@address.com
fi
```

X holds the number of KB used, if greater than 999000 it emails a warning message.

Comment: Correct, but this counts the space *used*...

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an `awk` to only deal with the second line (skips the first here) and get you your column:

```
$ df /dev/mapper/sil_acababdfabcf1 | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
11903752
```

Comment: Thanks, awk does look like a better alternative than `tail` and `cut`, thanks. I'll use that next time. For now I was able to use the nicer semantics provided by @muru's answer.